# Loading a pdf from folder in win8 metro apps

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1

I am trying to load a pdf file from a folder in my win8 app. It is in the test folder. I try

```
StorageFile file = StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Test/example.pdf"));
```

That gives me a file not found. However, if I change the extension of example.pdf to jpg, then change the code to look for example.jpg, it does work properly. What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public async Task<StorageFile> GetFileAsync(string directory, string fileName)
{
    string filePath = BuildPath(directory, fileName);
    string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);

    StorageFolder storageFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(directoryName);
    StorageFile storageFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
    return storageFile;
}

public string BuildPath(string directoryPath, string fileName)
{
    string directory = Path.Combine(Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, directoryPath);
    return Path.Combine(directory, fileName);
}
```

From your client, pass-in the directory (relative to the project) path of the file and then supply the file name for the second parameter.

In addition, it's probably good that you just create a library to manage various file operations.